# What is a token in perl?

Tags: perl

My assignment is to open and read a file, remove all commas, periods, spaces, and exclamation points from it. Furthermore, I must display the number of word occurrences for each word by placing the word as a hash and the number of occurrences as the value and the words are the keys. For example, in a document that says," Perl Program, Perl Program." Perl and program are the keys, where as the values are the n

Words-----Count

Perl------2

Program---2

The instructor already posted the directions, but in them he mentions, "split the line into tokens and store the array". I think I could do this if I knew what tokens were, so could someone explain what tokens are please?

Comment: Isn't this a question better directed to your instructor? I'd assume by "tokens" he simply means whatever parts you split the line into.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization

Comment: A better Wikipedia link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Token

Answer (score 4):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_%28parser%29#Token)

> A token is a string of characters, categorized according to the rules
>   as a symbol (e.g., IDENTIFIER, NUMBER, COMMA).

There is no special meaning of **token** in Perl.

Answer (score 0):

in this context a token is most likely a word/symbol that is broken up by a special character, which would be all the characters you are supposed to ignore.

That means in your example the tokens you'd have would be (in order)

```
Perl
Program
Perl
Program
```

But in another example that wasn't spaced out like

```
"Perl!ProgramHello,Name.GoodBye>ASFDKLDJ"
```

The tokens would be

```
Perl
ProgramHello (even though this is two english words)
Name
GoodBye
ASFDKLDJ
```

You should clarify with your Professor as to what you have to split the tokens on.

Comment: Tokens are not just words. The tokens in the example you give, using typical lexical analysis for a programming language, are: `Perl` `!` `ProgramHello` `,` `Name` `.` `GoodBye` `>` `ASFDKLDJ`. (Unless the quotes are part of the example, in which case it will probably be a single token which is a quoted string.) You cannot split tokens "on" something, because there is not necessarily a delimiter that you can use (i.e. you can't use Perl's split function). Instead, you usually need to write a finite state machine that recognizes the transition from one token to the next.

Comment: `you can't use Perl's split function`? `split/\b/`?

Comment: I'm confused... I'm not sure that this program is that serious. I'm only trying to put the words (apart from any commas,periods,exclamation points, quotes) into an array and compare it against itself to determine the number oof times each word occurs in a document. I tried split, split isn't working. It only takes one delimiter, I need it to take like 5, and delete them leaving only the words... So, I'm stuck.

Comment: T J, [split](http://p3rl.org/split.html) takes a regex, not a fixed string. You can stuff as many delimiters into the pattern as you like.

Comment: ??? Example? I must have the syntax incorrect then, because it isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with some text file with space as a standard word delimiter, the instructions do not say that while removing space and punctuation some other delimiter cannot be substituted.